# Issue with the Uint256

Tags: overflow

This is my first post here , I was not able to find the answer to my issue when I searched . 
I am using Remix with Metamask , 
I created the contract and using the following code to mint .I have a minting limit in the contract . however the token is showing me the total supply as 
a huge value "10000000000000000000" which is already higher than by total supply limit, because of which the check on minting stops the execution .

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
   function mint(uint noOfTokens) returns (bool) {
      checkTokens = _totalSupply.add(noOfTokens); 
   // Check the max limit and the owner before minting 
   require(_totalSupply <= maxLimit 
            && checkTokens <= maxLimit 
            && (msg.sender == address(owner)));
    balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(noOfTokens);
   _totalSupply        = _totalSupply.add(noOfTokens);
   return true;
```

}

The variables are defined as uint256.

Thanks for the help and support .
NKB.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

//ERC20 interface 
import './ERC20.sol';
// safe math for over and under value attack. 
import './SafeMath.sol';

contract Test is ERC20 {
    // using safe math for uint256
    using SafeMath for uint256;

```
uint256 public constant maxLimit = 500000000; 
uint256 public  _totalSupply = 0; 
string public constant symbol = "Test";
string public constant name = "TestCoin";
uint8 public constant decimals = 0;
// Rate -> 1 Ether = 1000 Just 
uint256 public RATE; 
// Ether reciever 
address public owner;
uint public start;
uint public startWeek;
uint public startTwoWeek;
uint public startFourWeek;
uint256 public tokens;
uint256 public checkTokens;

mapping(address=> uint256) balances; 
mapping(address=>mapping(address=>uint256)) allowed;


 // Fallback function
 // The function without name is the default function that is called 
 // whenever anyone sends funds to a contract

function() payable{
    createTokens();
}

function Test(){
   // balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
owner  = msg.sender;  // get the owner of the token
start  = now;  // Get the current block time 
startWeek = start + 30 minutes ; // Get the scond block time
startTwoWeek = start + 60 minutes; // Get the third block time 
startFourWeek = start + 90 minutes; // Get the fourth block time . 

}

// Create new tokens
   function mint(uint noOfTokens) returns (bool) {
      checkTokens = _totalSupply.add(noOfTokens); 
   // Check the max limit and the owner before minting 
   require(_totalSupply/1000000000000000000 <= maxLimit 
            && checkTokens/1000000000000000000 <= maxLimit 
            && (msg.sender == address(owner)));
    balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(noOfTokens);
   _totalSupply     = _totalSupply.add(noOfTokens);
   return true;
```

}

```
 function createTokens() payable {
    require(msg.value >0 && _totalSupply <= maxLimit);

    if (now <= startWeek   && now > start) {
    RATE =    1150; 
    tokens = msg.value.mul(RATE);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
}

 if (now <= startTwoWeek && now > startWeek ) {
    RATE =    1100;
    tokens = msg.value.mul(RATE);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
 }

if (now <= startFourWeek && now > startTwoWeek ) {
    RATE =    1050;
    tokens = msg.value.mul(RATE);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
 }
 if (now > startFourWeek ) {
    RATE =    1000;
    tokens = msg.value.mul(RATE);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
 }


}
  function totalSupply() constant returns (uint totalSupply){
      return _totalSupply;
  }

  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance){
      return balances[_owner];
  }

  function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success){
      require( balances[msg.sender] >= _value &&
          _value > 0 );
          balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value) ;
          balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
          Transfer(msg.sender,_to,_value);
          return true;
  }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success){
      require( allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value &&
      balances[_from] >= _value
      && _value > 0 );
    balances[_from]  = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to]    = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender]  = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from,_to,_value);
    return true;
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success){
   allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
   Approval(msg.sender,_spender,_value);
   return true;

  }

  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint remaining){
    return allowed [_owner][_spender];  
  }
  event GoalReached(address beneficiary, uint amountRaised);
  event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
  event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);
```

}

[image]
even though the token is defined with zero decimals it picks up 18 decimals for the wei and puts the value with all the decimals .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have your **`decimals`** set to **`18`**, you have to then divide by **`1,000,000,000,000,000,000`** *(1 followed by 18 zeros)* to get the integer-value of **`_totalSupply.`**

18 decimals is the standard for Ethereum. The smallest unit is referred to as a **Wei**. 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 wei are equal to 1 Ether. [**Here is a unit map.**](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/0.15.0/lib/utils/utils.js#L40)

To simplify your contract you could set the decimals to **`0`**, in which case you would only be dealing with integer values that are NOT divisible. The downside is that you could **NOT** then offer **fractions of a token.**

Comment: Thanks for your response , I understand I will try now and update here .

Comment: Hi nyusternie, I tried the second option to keep the decimals as 0 ,but it still the same .                                                                                       
    uint256 public constant maxLimit = 500000000; 
    uint256 public  _totalSupply = 0; 
    string public constant symbol = "TEST";
    string public constant name = "TestCoin001";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

Comment: reduce the decimals to **0** `uint8 public constant decimals = 0;` and then increase the total supply to some number greater than or equal to `maxLimit` `uint256 public _totalSupply = <enter-total-supply-here>;`