# How to send ERC20 tokens in decimals?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens

ERC20 token standards have a variable call decimals but all its functions parameters are uint256, how can I send tokens in decimals. Ex: 0.01 MFT (MyFirstToken)

Comment: Or: [Decimals on ERC-20 tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/decimals-on-erc20-tokens)

Comment: According to the second link that you shared, there are no actual decimal values? Just integers?

Comment: @KashishKhullar yep, thats why Ether has Wei as the smallest unit. Because if the price of Ether will skyrocket we still have 18 decimal places to play around with a smaller units. There are tokens like IOTA which are very small and to trade real values with them the [IOTa system of units](https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/4xkja2/iota_system_of_units/) was made. You can make such system for your own Token.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a floating point number in Ethereum. Everything is a 'wei'.  An ether is 10^18 wei. The `decimals` value in the token standard is an indication to wallets and other tools that handle ERC20 tokens instructing them how best to display the token.