# How to execute the Transfer function from Remix

Tags: remix

I deployed this ERC-20 contract https://github.com/sijo0703/solidity-contracts/blob/master/MyToken.sol in Remix via the JavaScript VM.

How can I transfer some Tokens from the contract creator's address (me) to another address from within Remix?  When I call the Transfer function using the Orange Button it fails.  I assume the Transfer function is being called using the Contract address which has no Tokens.

How can I initiate the Transfer function via the contract creator's address (me) from within the Remix IDE?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deploying the ERC-20, your address receives the total supply of the token, as you can see here :

```
    constructor( uint256 _totalSupply) public{
    totalSupply_ = _totalSupply;
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
}
```

_totalSupply is a constructor parameter so you have to fulfill the corresponding section in Remix. Be aware of the decimal system of the ERC-20 : if you want 10000 units with 3 decimals, `_totalSupply` will be equal to 10000*10^3 (more info here : [Decimals on ERC20 Tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/decimals-on-erc20-tokens)).

> When I call the Transfer function using the Orange Button it fails. I assume the Transfer function is being called using the Contract address which has no Tokens.

The contract address does not need tokens, the sender (you in this case) does. In addition you need some ETH to pay the gas fees.

> How can I transfer some Tokens from the contract creator's address (me) to another address from within Remix?

Just call `transfer` with the same address that the one you used to deploy. Be sure to respect the following condition :

```
require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
```

Send an amount <= your balance which is equal to the token total supply after the deployment.

Comment: "Just call transfer with the same address that the one you used to deploy. Be sure to respect the following condition"  This is what I don't know how to do in Remix.  I don't know how to specify the calling address... the default address is the contract address.  Too bad I can't paste screenshots here.

Comment: I figured it out.  I thought the Account was just for showing me the available addresses but the chosen account is what actually executes the transactions.  I understand now.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: I deployed my contract to Rinkeby.  Everything works fine.  However, I noticed when I perform a TransferFrom transaction and allowance reaches 0, I get a Gas Estimation Error in Remix.  Shouldn't Remix allow the transaction to go through and then "require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);" should trap the Error?

Comment: I think I figured out this one too.  At the end of the message it says "always failing transaction".  So this message combines both running out of Gas and a heads up that your Transaction will always fail.

Comment: Remix has very generic error messages. If you have further questions, please open a new post.