# What's the default erc20 decimals?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, erc-20, contract-deployment

As we know, decimals is an optional parameter on ERC20.

I was wondering what if decimals is not set on a contract.

Does it mean that if I send 10 in the transfer function, it means that it actually transfers 10? Does this mean that default decimals is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that not specifying decimals, would treat it as 0.

It sounds tautological, but to answer your related questions, a totalSupply of 100 would be 100 tokens, and a transfer of 10, would transfer 10 tokens.

---

When using decimals, make sure to see this question because it does affect the values for totalSupply and transfer amounts: [Decimals on ERC20 Tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/decimals-on-erc20-tokens)?

Answer (score 0):

The `transfer()` function does not care if there are decimals or not. It is purely a cosmetic divisor for human display.

Comment: Yeap. true, but my actual question is if user has 10 tokens on a ERC20 contract which doesn't have `decimals` property stored on it, does this mean user has actually 10 tokens  ?

Comment: mainly, I am asking that if you don't have `decimals` property on a contract, then what would be the default `decimals` ?

Comment: The `transfer()` function does not care. There is an `uint256` number and it can present whatever you want.

Comment: I know, i know .. I am asking something else. Let's say I deploy ERC20 without `decimals` property and totalSupply as 100..  Now, when users look at my contracts and see totalSupply, what will they think ?  totalSupply is 100 or totalSupply is 100*10**18 ? Basically, without `decimals` , what's the default `decimals` on ERC20 ?